# In Swift, Why am I getting an error when trying to covert from a string to a date?

Tags: string, date, swift, textfield

I have tried several solutions to stop this error, but have failed. My error is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let datef = NSDateFormatter()
datef.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
var mydate = datef.dateFromString(textfieldjobdate.text)
println("\(textfieldjobdate.text) date is coming up as: \(mydate)")
newItem.custjobdatestart = mydate
```

Even the println button shows there is a problem. In the textield, which is populated by a datepicker the date is in the format dd MMM yyyy if that helps.

I need the result to be an NSDate to be able to save the value to my CoreData Database

Comment: Why do you not put the `NSDate` from the date picker in a seperate variable to save that one in the entity, and then use `stringFromDate` to populate the date in the text field? This way you only convert in one way, and not back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because `dateFromString` returns nil. It returns nil because input string doesn't match specified date format.

In Xcode 6 playground:

```
let datef = NSDateFormatter()
datef.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
datef.dateFormat  // "MMM d, y"
```

Solution: set date format to "dd MMM yyyy" directly:

```
datef.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
```